# LINQ to SQL select equal OR not equal to

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

In the following LINQ query, i would like when the Loc=Locale.Gr all the records with GrID=100 returned and when the Loc is anything else all the other records with GrID <> 100 returned.

How can i achieve this one? I tried something like the following, but it is totally wrong.

```
PrivateSub Test(Byval Loc as Locale)
    Private Const GrID as integer = 100
    Dim Query = From c In Mob Where c.CountryID = IIf(Loc = Locale.Gr, GrID, <> GrID) select c
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Of course i could use something like

```
If Loc = Locale.Gr Then
 Query = From c In Mob Where c.CountryID = GrID 
Else
 Query = From c In Mob Where Not c.CountryID = GrID 
End If
```

but it is not elegand

Answer (score 1):

Think about it in a logical way - you have two conditions when you want a record returned:

> Loc = Locale.Gr AND GrID = 100
>
> Loc <> Locale.Gr AND GrId <> 100

Now make a `Where` clause by combining both of these conditions with an OR (since only one of them is going to be true) and you have your query.

Comment: Hello sir, i think sometimes i am thinking too complicated but the AND will never be TRUE (second line) since the GrID is declared as a Const with a value of 100

Comment: @Chocol8: What does this mean in your question then: *"when the Loc is anything else all the other records with GrID <> 100 returned"* ?

Comment: Hello Sir but my English is horrible. Can you please see the update?